# Redirecting to /pub/setup after migration

Tags: magento2

[image]I recently moved my Magento shop to new VPS from hostinger, what i did is:

Copied all the folders and files from public_html and pasted to VPS on a domain public_html directory as it is.

Exported and imported the database.

And changed the nameservers, after a complete propagation of nameservers the website is taking load and ended up err too many redirects to /pub/setup page.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your website is redirecting to the/pub/setup page, so check for the possible steps to reproduce:

- Which version of Magento 2 are you using?
- After the database dump, did you set your domain name correctly like:

  In the database table **core_config_data**, check if the URL is correctly configured.

  UPDATE core_config_data
  SET value = 'http://helloworld.in/'
  WHERE path IN ('web/secure/base_url', 'web/unsecure/base_url');

  UPDATE core_config_data
  SET value = REPLACE(value, 'http://helloworld.com/', 'http://helloworld.in/')
  WHERE path = 'design/head/includes';

or using the command:

```
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://helloworld.in/"
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://helloworld.in/"
```

- if you are using **Apache**:

  Run the composer install command in the root directory of Magento and put that directory in the DocumentRoot of Apache.
- Make sure the Apache rewrite module is enabled and installed with mod_php.
- If you are using Magento 2.4.3, then you should upgrade to 2.4.x latest version coz this issue was reproducible in the previous versions. Check the [doc](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36694)
- Web setup wizard was used only in the previous version of Magento 2.
- Install the setup via the command line once the install process checks the setup table to work out where it is in terms of versions. Once installed, reset it back again to public_html/pub clear cache, and it seemed fine.

Comment: I have tried each step one by one but i am stuck at installing composer, when i am trying to install it, it is asking for marketplace credentials.

Comment: Enter the marketplace credentials from https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/, if you don't know how to get the keys follow this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html